# Foregin key Index name Size error in php laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel, migration, size

I'm getting an error during migration which is mention below:

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1059 Identifier name 'port_call_departure_time_readings_port_call_departure_time_condition_id_foreign' is too long (SQL: alter table port_call_departure_time_readings add index port_call_departure_time_readings_port_call_departure_time_condition_id_foreign(port_call_departure_time_condition_id)):`

Allowing size for FK index name is 59 and I have tested this during migration.
But orignal FK index name size is 79.

Can you please explain to me what would be the best solution to assign the FK index name in the port_call_departure_time_readings table for a port_call_departure_time_condition_id field?

Comment: May I see your migration code?

Answer (score 4):

Try this `$table->index('column','index_name')`

Answer (score 1):

The `foreign()` method accepts an index name as its second parameter. For example:

```php
$table->foreign('user_id', 'your_index_name_foreign')
      ->references('id')->on('users');
```

When you don't specify a name, Laravel defaults to concatenating the table and column names. In some cases, the default name is longer than your database allows for an index.

Comment: but I was not using the default name.

Comment: @KashifAhmed so you *manually* named your foreign key `port_call_departure_time_readings_port_call_departure_time_condition_id_foreign` ? It would help if you include the migration code